# Можно ли использовать знак вопроса в таком предложении? Аргументируйте, пожалуйста

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, обращение, вопрос, знак

Александр, давайте встретимся в понедельник?

Answer (score 3):

***Александр, давайте встретимся в понедельник(?)***

Нет, лучше так: ***Александр, может быть, встретимся в понедельник?***

Вопрос интересный.

1. Теоретически в **побудительных предложениях** (давайте встретимся) вопросительной интонации быть не должно.

Предложения с точки зрения выраженного в них содержания, то есть по цели высказывания, бывают **повествовательные, вопросительные и побудительные.**

**Побудительное предложение** — это предложение, которое содержит повеление, просьбу или запрет. В конце повелительного предложения, в зависимости от того, произносится оно спокойным или повышенным тоном, ставится **точка или восклицательный знак.** https://izamorfix.ru/rus/sint_punkt/vidy_predlozheniy.html

2. Но, может быть, **есть частные случаи**. В этом плане интересны предложения с частицей **«давай».**

Для образования форм совместного действия часто используются частицы ***давай, давайте*** с формой 1-го лица мн. числа или с инфинитивом: давайте пойдём в кино, давайте обедать, давайте читать.

3. В  заданном предложении мы действительно **не можем поставить знак вопроса,** так как неясно, к какой части предложения будет относиться вопросительная интонация.

Но, как мне кажется, возможно такое предложение:

***Смотри, цены на путевки снижены. ДавАй поедем?***

Здесь повышение голоса (вопросительная интонация) делается **на побудительной частице**, что в принципе возможно. Но предложение **не должно быть** распространенным.